# Creating a Loop to Paste Multiple Sheet Ranges to Power Point as Pictures

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have been trying to modify this below code but receiving an error `Script out of range` on the line   `ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1)`.

The code is take the `Status of Col"E"` If it is = Include then its corresponding sheets ranges will be pasted as picture to Power Point.

But this is not working your help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

```
Sub SelectSheets_Ranges()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, arrSplit, i As Long, k As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  ReDim arr(lastR - 1)
  For i = 5 To lastR
        If sh.Range("E" & i).Value = "Include" Then
            arr(k) = sh.Range("C" & i).Value & "|" & sh.Range("D" & i).Value: k = k + 1
        End If
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        arrSplit = Split(arr(i), "|")
        Set rng = Worksheets(arrSplit(0)).Range(arrSplit(1))

''''
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
On Error Resume Next

      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
      Err.Clear
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
  rng.Copy

  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
      myShape.Left = 66
      myShape.Top = 152
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  '''''''''
  
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly you must not declare variables and create PowerPoint object in each loop... I will try looking to your code. `lastR = sh.Range("A"...` should be calculated for `lastR = sh.Range("C"...`, for C:C column... It may differ, you maybe do not have any rows in column A:A...

Comment: Yes i did not. after your commnet i edited the `lastR = sh.Range("A"...`  to Col"C" and it is working fine but it is creating new files for each sheet. All Sheets ranges picture should come in file but in separate pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use the next code:

```
Sub SelectSheets_Ranges()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, arrSplit, i As Long, k As Long
  Dim PowerPointApp As Object, myPresentation As Object, mySlide As Object, myShape As Object
  
    On Error Resume Next
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")
      err.Clear
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")
      If err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If
   On Error GoTo 0
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add 
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("C" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  ReDim arr(lastR - 1)
  For i = 5 To lastR
        If sh.Range("E" & i).value = "Include" Then
            arr(k) = sh.Range("C" & i).value & "|" & sh.Range("D" & i).value: k = k + 1
        End If
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        arrSplit = Split(arr(i), "|")
        Set rng = Worksheets(arrSplit(0)).Range(arrSplit(1))

          Application.ScreenUpdating = False          
          Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
          rng.Copy
        
          mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
          Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.count)
              myShape.left = 66
              myShape.top = 152
          PowerPointApp.Visible = True
          PowerPointApp.Activate
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the above code is creating new files for each range separately. All Sheets ranges picture should come in single file but in separate pages

Comment: @Valiant: Please, try the updated code. I could not test it...

Comment: Very humble thank you @FaneDuru for the help. I would request just last thing. That how the Power Point page can be adjusted according to the ranges Pictures. Because pictures are coming out of the pages.

Comment: @Valiant: I do not work with PowerPoint at all...  But, do you want readjusting the page, not the picture dimensions? Shouldn't the page be the same, standard?

Comment: I really do not know which one is better.  You must have better experience which one will be good. I just need to adjust the pictures on the pages so it may look better.

Comment: @Valiant: then, I would suggest to play with the picture height and width...

Comment: Ok i will follow.

Comment: Can i use this same code to convert the sheets ranges into PDF @FaneDuru

Comment: @Valiant:  You can use the (same) code **to set which range to be exported**. Then, of course, you must use a piece of code able to make this export (hint: use `Range.ExportAsFixedFormat`).

Comment: Thank you very much i will try to make these changes.

Comment: Can you please do this or should i post a new question i have tried but couldn't make this. @FaneDuru

Comment: Updated a question please answer when you have time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67807934/convert-multiple-excel-sheet-ranges-as-pdf-vba @FaneDuru