# Convert Multiple Excel Sheet Ranges as PDF VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

The below code is take the Status of Col"E" If it is = Include then its corresponding sheets ranges will will be converted to PDF.

I have tried at my end but its not working receiving an error `invalid procedure call or argument` on the line

```
rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=saveLocation
```

Your help will be appreciated to fix the problem.

[image]

```
Sub SelectSheets_Ranges()

  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, arrSplit, i As Long, k As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  ReDim arr(lastR - 1)
  For i = 6 To lastR
        If sh.Range("E" & i).Value = "Include" Then
            arr(k) = sh.Range("C" & i).Value & "|" & sh.Range("D" & i).Value: k = k + 1
        End If
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        arrSplit = Split(arr(i), "|")
        Set rng = Worksheets(arrSplit(0)).Range(arrSplit(1))


'Create and assign variables
Dim saveLocation As String

saveLocation = "C:\Users\marks\OneDrive\Documents\myPDFFile.pdf"

'Save a range as PDF
rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=saveLocation

  
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're creating multiple outputs but it looks like you're always using the same file location to save to?

Comment: Yes you are right. The file can be saved to the similar folder where the excel file is already saved. There is no need to save the file on different location.

Comment: But you have multiple files to save in a run?  You can't export one file like this.

Comment: Yes i have to convert the multiple sheets ranges into PDF in one run. then how it can be possible.

Comment: Into a *single* PDF?   Are the sheets set up with only the ranges listed as the print area?

Comment: Yes into Single PDF each page would have single range. Yes sheets are setup with ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It saves in `ThisWorkbook` path, naming the pdf file as "myPDFFile_sheetName.pdf". Each created file will be open in the default pdf application. If it works OK, you can appropriately change the last parameter:

```
Sub SelectSheets_Ranges_ExpPdf()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, arrSplit, i As Long, k As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  ReDim arr(lastR - 1)
  For i = 6 To lastR
        If sh.Range("E" & i).Value = "Include" Then
            arr(k) = sh.Range("C" & i).Value & "|" & sh.Range("D" & i).Value: k = k + 1
        End If
  Next i
  If k > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1)
  Else
        MsgBox "No appropriate range (containing ""Include"") could be found...:exit sub"
  End If
  Dim boolHide As Boolean, boolProt As Boolean
  ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "4321" 'in order to unprotect he workbook structure
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        boolHide = False: boolProt = False
        arrSplit = Split(arr(i), "|")
        Set rng = Worksheets(arrSplit(0)).Range(arrSplit(1))
        
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arrSplit(0)).ProtectContents Then _
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arrSplit(0)).Unprotect "4321": boolProt = True
                Debug.Print arrSplit(0)
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arrSplit(0)).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then _
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arrSplit(0)).Visible = xlSheetVisible: boolHide = True
        
        'Create and assign variables
        Dim saveLocation As String
        
        saveLocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\myPDFFile_" & arrSplit(0) & ".pdf"
        
        'Save a range as PDF
        rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
          saveLocation, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
         If boolHide Then ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arrSplit(0)).Visible = xlSheetHidden
         If boolProt Then ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arrSplit(0)).Protect "4321"
  Next
  ActiveWorkbook.Protect "4321"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much but receiving an error `invalid procedure call or argument` on the line `rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
          saveLocation, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True` @FaneDuru

Comment: @Valiant: The code is checked and it works. Let us debug and see what happens in your case. Are you sure that the columns keeping "Include" string is E:E column and this one starts from the row 6?

Comment: Yes i am sure and i rechecked all the Column reference.

Comment: @Valiant: Please, insert this code line `Debug.Print rng.Address, k:stop` immediately after `Set rng = Worksheets(...`. What does it return in Immediate Window when the code stops on `Stop` command?

Comment: This is appear `$B$5:$R$66`

Comment: @Valiant: Please, try running the code line by line, pressing F8 for each line. Where the code stops on error?

Comment: stops on this line `rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _           saveLocation, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True` @FaneDuru

Comment: @Valiant: Is this part of the code `IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True` on the same code line?

Comment: @Valiant: I am not available for some time. Can you share your workbook, to make some tests?

Comment: Yes i can share but no publically it contains the office details.

Comment: I think the problem is occurring due to worksheets are hide.

Comment: @Valiant: Of course, this can be a reason. I will adapt the code to check if the sheet is hidden and if yes, to unhide it.

Comment: @Valiant: Please, try the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: I tried with you code but now the error is appearing on `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arrSplit(0)).Visible = xlSheetVisible` i thing this is due to protective workbook it tried with  `ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="4321"` before and after your sheet hide and unhide code but nothing work. @FaneDuru error is `unable to set the visible property of the worksheet class`

Comment: @Valiant: Why do you come with such pieces of information in consecutive steps? You have to unprotect **the sheet**! Do you know its protect password?

Comment: I apologize i wasn't aware that these information would be required. Yes protected with password and the password is `4321`

Comment: @Valiant: I will adapt the code to also unprotect the sheet if the case...

Comment: @Valiant:  Please, test the updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233245/discussion-between-valiant-and-faneduru).

Comment: @Valiant: Please, test the updated code. It should work now. The workbook has its structure protected...

Comment: @Valiant: Glad I could (finally) help... But it should be good to know that all these aspects (protected structure, protected sheets, hidden sheets) should be clearly stated in your question...

Comment: Please have a look into this @FaneDuru  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937035/create-single-pdf-file-rather-than-multiple?r=SearchResults&s=1|33.6370)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub SelectSheets_Ranges()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim saveLocation As String, FirstSheet As Boolean
    
    saveLocation = "C:\Users\marks\OneDrive\Documents\myPDFFile.pdf"
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    FirstSheet = True
    For i = 6 To sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If sh.Cells(i, "E") = "Include" Then
            'FirstSheet determines whether the sheet is added to currently-selected 
            '  sheets or not (if not then it replaces them)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Cells(i, "C").Value).Select FirstSheet
            FirstSheet = False
        End If
    Next i
    If Not FirstSheet Then
        'at least one sheet was included
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveLocation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir this error is occur on the line https://ibb.co/Srbss2Z `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Cells(i, "C").Value).Select FirstSheet` while running the code. @Tim Williams

Comment: Are the worksheets listed in the same workbook as the code, and are they all visible (ie not Hidden)?

Comment: Yes workbook is same but the problem is sheets are hidden.

Comment: You will need to unhide the sheets if you want to export them all to the same file.

Comment: I understand now but there can be any way to perform this on hidden sheets.

Comment: You can't select a hidden sheet, so No you can't do this with hidden sheets.  You can have the code unhide and then re-hide them though: the user will not notice if you turn off screenupdating.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want all the ranges from the different sheets in one pdf.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SelectSheets_Ranges()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\Users\marks\OneDrive\Documents\"
    Const FILENAME = "myPDFFile.pdf"

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbPDF As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wsPDF As Worksheet
    Dim lastR As Long, rng As Range, r As Long, n As Integer, m As Integer
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    lastR = sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' create temp workbook to hold ranges
    Set wbPDF = Workbooks.Add
    m = wbPDF.Sheets.Count
    n = m
    With sh
        For r = 6 To lastR
            If .Cells(r, "E").Value = "Include" Then
                Set rng = wb.Sheets(.Cells(r, "C").Value).Range(.Cells(r, "D").Value)
                Set wsPDF = wbPDF.Sheets.Add(After:=wbPDF.Sheets(n))
                rng.Copy wsPDF.Range("A1")
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' delete initial sheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For n = m To 1 Step -1
       wbPDF.Sheets(n).Delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    'end
    wbPDF.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FILENAME:=FOLDER & FILENAME
    'wbPDF.SaveAs FOLDER & "debug.xlsx"
    wbPDF.Close False
    MsgBox "PDF created " & FOLDER & FILENAME, vbInformation

End Sub
```